# R Shiny: Change default colour for tabPanel title

Tags: html, r, colors, shiny

If you run the following code (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798850/change-background-color-of-tabpanel-when-it-is-active-or-hover-over-in-shiny)), the "title2" and "title3" appear in grey colour by default. How can I change this default color from a grey colour to a e.g. "white" colour?

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- function(){
  navbarPage(title = 'Hello', 
             tabPanel("title2"),
             tabPanel("title3"),
             tags$head(
               tags$style(type = 'text/css', 
                          HTML('.navbar { background-color: red;}
                               .navbar-default .navbar-brand{color: white;}
                               .tab-panel{ background-color: red; color: white}
                               .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
                               .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, 
                               .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
                               color: #555;
                               background-color: green;
                               }')
                          )
                          )
                          )

}

server <- function(input, output, session){
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Press ctrl+shift+c (assuming you're not on a mac). A developer's tool should popup. Point your mouse to the desired HTML element and css to it should appear on the right (approximately). You should be able to track back where css is defined and change it.

Comment: Thank you ... So to just give the answer. All I need was to add ".navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {color: white;}"

Comment: Please add this as an answer.