# Background color of navlistpanel/tabpanel

Tags: css, r, filter, shinydashboard, tabpanel

I actually want something similar as posted here 
[Change background color of tabPanel when it is active or hover over in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798850/change-background-color-of-tabpanel-when-it-is-active-or-hover-over-in-shiny)

instead of navbarpage i want to use navlistpanel.

I have two annoying issues regarding the layout of my Dashboard. I added a picture to show what i mean. The default is this blueish colour, but i would like it to be red as a background and the color white as font. Now I kind of managed to do so, but still if you are standig/selecting the topic test1 then it's blue. How can i change or fix this?

Next thing, preferably I want to have test1 and then a submenu right below test 1 to do the filtering. Then i call that filters, and then i would like to add the two filters group variable and filter op datum.

Can anyone please help me out!

Now the filters are positioned are positioned outside the navlistpanel.

Kind regards,

Steffie

```
 navlistPanel(well = FALSE, 



      tabPanel(new="", windowTitle="Test",
               h4(id = "new","Test"),
               tags$style("#new{color: white; background-color: #d52b1e;}"),    

        fluidRow(
        # column(1), ## this put an extra space, dont like the look
        column(2,
               sidebarMenu(
                 uiOutput("groups")), 

        ),
        # fluidRow(
          # column(2,offset = 1),
          column(3,
                 sidebarMenu(
                 dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                                label = 'Filter op datum',
                                start = as.Date('2019-01-01') , end = as.Date('2019-12-31')
                 )
               ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use css to change the colour of the navigation pills when selected. Place the css tags in the `fluidpage` using `tags$head`. To have options under a tab panel use `navbarMenu` and place the `tabPanel` calls with the `navbarMenu` call.

With regards to your questions in the comments, you originally set `WELL=FALSE` in your `navlistPanel` call. If you set it to `TRUE`, a box is placed around the `navlistPanel` bar. To change the background colour of this, we again make use of CSS, using the `.well` property. With this you can change font size, font, font color, background color, maximum width and height of the `navlistPanel` and so much more.

What does the syntax mean? Most of it is quite intuitive. I recommend changing some of the values like `font-family` to see what's actually going on. Also make use of the `css` tag right here on Stackoverflow. You can also learn more about css [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp).

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked > .active > a, .nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked > .active > a:hover {
    background-color: #d52b1e;
  }

.well {
    min-height: 20px;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;

}

                            "))),

  navlistPanel(well = TRUE,

               navbarMenu("Tests",

                          tabPanel("Test1",
                                   fluidRow(
                                     # column(1), ## this put an extra space, dont like the look
                                     column(2,
                                            sidebarMenu(
                                              uiOutput("groups")), 

                                     ),
                                     # fluidRow(
                                     # column(2,offset = 1),
                                     column(3,
                                            sidebarMenu(
                                              dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                                                             label = 'Filter op datum',
                                                             start = as.Date('2019-01-01') , end = as.Date('2019-12-31')
                                              )
                                            ),
                                     )
                                   )

                          ),
                          tabPanel("Test 2",
                                   "UI elements here")

               ),


               tabPanel("Other",
                        "UI elements here")
  )

)


server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it is almost doing exactly what I like. So you helped me out incredibly well! I just would like to understand the syntax a bitter better. For example it's not necessary, but if i would like the whole background of the navlist to be red, how could i arrange that? For example how would i be able to change te colour of the font which is blue now when you dont select it? Maybe very stupid, but i'm really really new to it. And stuff changing font size and stuff? You helped me out so much, it would be cool to be able play around with it a bit more.

Comment: OMG, im a fan! Thank you so much!